# Widescreen hack in Deus Ex: Invisible War not working

Tags: deus-ex-invisible-war

I tried the WSGF Wiki hack to get DX:IW working in widescreen (1080p) but it's not working. Even changing the resolution inside the game does not seem to have an effect.

All I get is a square with the game in and big vertical bands at both sides.

Can anybody help me? It's really unplayable this way :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the new DirectX 10 renderer? You can find a good tutorial to install and configure the widescreen support [here](http://www.widescreengamingforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=190534#p190534).